# Finding <body> html on thesis theme

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm having trouble finding the `<body>` in the thesis theme in wordpress as i need to add a (`itemscope itemtype=""`) on it. Anyone could help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Leo

Comment: I do not know the theme, but the opening <body> tag is most often in header.php, right below the closing head tag.

Comment: Hello bro, Yeah i had tried to allocate it on the skin content but it doesn't appear when i scanned from the header to footer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the skin editor. Then hover the body and click the cog/gear, then you can set the class and any other details you need I think.